# Camunda Modeler cannot open '.bpmn' files created in Oracle BPM

Tags: eclipse, bpmn, camunda

I'm trying to open .bpmn files in Camunda Modeler that are created in Oracle BPM Suite and I get some warnings/exceptions and the model diagram doesn't show up. How do I get around this.?

I eventually have to deploy these models to local camunda instance (tomcat distro or jboss distro) but this is where I got stuck.

I tried both the standalone Camunda Modeler 1.3.0 and the Eclipse plugin too without any luck.

Here's the stack trace:

```html
org.camunda.bpm.modeler.core.importer.ResourceImportException: Import warning : org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'fileRevision' not found. (platform:/resource/.internal/C.Users.DARIPIJA.Documents.PolicyEvaluationProcess.bpmn, 2, 343)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.core.importer.ModelImport.logResourceErrors(ModelImport.java:947)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.core.importer.ModelImport.<init>(ModelImport.java:157)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.core.importer.ModelImportCommand.doExecute(ModelImportCommand.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.RecordingCommand.execute(RecordingCommand.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.editor.GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.execute(GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:117)
 at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.execute(AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.java:219)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.importDiagram(Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.java:97)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.access$0(Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.java:89)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2RefreshBehavior$1.doExecute(Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.RecordingCommand.execute(RecordingCommand.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.EMFCommandOperation.doExecute(EMFCommandOperation.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.AbstractEMFOperation.execute(AbstractEMFOperation.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.DefaultOperationHistory.execute(DefaultOperationHistory.java:513)
 at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.impl.WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.doExecute(WorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:208)
 at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.execute(AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.java:165)
 at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.internal.editor.GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.execute(GFWorkspaceCommandStackImpl.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.execute(AbstractTransactionalCommandStack.java:219)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.importBpmnDiagram(Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.java:70)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.autoUpdate(Bpmn2RefreshBehavior.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.editor.DefaultRefreshBehavior.handleAutoUpdateAtStartup(DefaultRefreshBehavior.java:101)
 at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.editor.DiagramBehavior.setInput(DiagramBehavior.java:392)
 at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.editor.DiagramEditor.setInput(DiagramEditor.java:300)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2Editor.setInput(Bpmn2Editor.java:284)
 at org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.editor.DiagramEditor.init(DiagramEditor.java:217)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2Editor.init(Bpmn2Editor.java:158)
 at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:239)
 at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:213)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.ui.diagram.editor.Bpmn2MultiPageEditor.createPages(Bpmn2MultiPageEditor.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:358)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:142)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:323)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1147)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:65)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
 at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:619)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1043)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
 at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2959)
 at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(IDE.java:1132)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:107)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenLocalFileAction.run(OpenLocalFileAction.java:76)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
 at org.camunda.bpm.modeler.standalone.ModelerApplication.start(ModelerApplication.java:63)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)    ​
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the BPMN2.0 that oracle creates is not 100% standard. Try opening it in http://demo.bpmn.io/ or signavio (if you have an account) to check if its a modeller problem.

Comment: I've tried both but get some errors (like `The diagram interchange part of BPMN 2.0 definitions is missing`) and warnings (like `the following shape was discarded, because no graphical information (DI element) could be found: UserTask (USER_TASK_127654812874)`). The reason _I think_ is Oracle modeler adds some custom oracle notation which is not obeyed by any open source/industry standard modeler available and the only way to work with it is to hand edit the xml or just to re-create the model. My statement needs to be validated though.!

Comment: I think you are right, but I cannot validate the statement due to lack of knowledge of the oracle bpmn format. If you could share the xml, I can try to analyse it. Otherwise I would suggest asking on the oracle or camunda list directly.